# Octopus Api - Get Environments by Lifecycle

Tags: octopus-deploy

I am writing an application that runs against the octopus 3.0 api and can't find a way around this.

We have dozens of environments that are logically split using a different lifecycle for different versions of our product.

What i want to be able to do is get all environments for version 1 of the product and then do the same for 3,4 etc.

Can anyone point me at the best way of doing this, or any other way of grouping environments?